# Execution Failed in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jvm

Getting this error when trying to debug a project in IntelliJ. Can anyone help?

Execution failed for task ':PasApplication.main()'.

> Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: Maybe enlighten us a bit more [Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is a problem with your java version in IntelliJ. Check this in settings:[image]